# WCF Windows Service does not log to Event Logs when hosted.

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, c#-4.0, windows-services

I have a WCF class library which I am hosting as a windows service. The problem is when I run the service in a debug mode as console app it logs properly to the event logs. But when I host it as a Windows service using a setup file I have created with inno setup it does not log anything for some reason.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<switches>
  <add name="Retail.ReaderService.Switch" value="4" />
</switches>
<trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
  <listeners>
    <add name="EventLogTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="ServiceLog" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I have these settings in the main app.config file. I tried changing the autoflush attribute to true but it does not work. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you run the program in debug mode, it's running as you, Govs. And if you're in the admin group on your machine, the program's running as administrator and it has rights to read/write the event logs. But when you're running the program as a windows service, it only has the rights assigned of that user account, which it appears does not have rights to write to the event log.

I had the same problem and wrote this function to detect whether I had the rights or not to write to the event log.

```
private void GetServicePermissionLevel()
{
bool bAdmin = false;
try {
    SecurityIdentifier sidAdmin = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
    AppDomain myDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
    myDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(sidAdmin)) {
        bAdmin = true;
    } else {
        bAdmin = false;
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception("Error in GetServicePermissionlevel(): " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.StackTrace);
} finally {
    _ServiceRunAsAdmin = bAdmin;
}
}
```

Then when I want to do some event logging, I use this:

```
if (_ServiceRunAsAdmin)
EventLog.WriteEntry(c_ServiceName, "Error in GetServiceHostParamSet: " + ex.Message + ". This parameter not found: " + sName);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am using trace.writeline to write the logs. Do you think it can also have the same problem?

Comment: Actually I am the admin on the computer. So I think this is not the issue. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Exactly ... when you run the program in debug mode, the program us running as administrator and, therefore, has rights to read/write to the event logs. But what about the windows service account you're running the program under? Probably doesn't have administrator rights. The code I included will find out of the user account the program is running under has administrator rights. Because without  admin rights, you can't write to the event log.

Comment: If I am reading this right doesn't this code just check if you have the rights but doesn't actually help solve the problem of it not writing?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. The solution is to ensure your system diagnostic settings that work for your WCF app are also set in the app.config of your windows service.  As soon as I copied mine over my logs appeared.